# switch to another video and repeat continuously

Tags: javascript, html

The HTML coed is

```
<video autoplay id="myvideo">
 <source id="vmp4" src="v1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source id="vogg" src="v1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
 <p>Your browser does not support this video format.</p>
</video>
```

What I want to do is that after page load and at the end of showing video1.mp4, switch to video2.mp4 after 5 seconds and repeat this continuously.
ie.
video1>5s>video2>5s>video1>...

```
var myvideo1 = ["v1.mp4", "v2.mp4"]
var myvideo2 = ["v1.ogg", "v2.ogg"]
var vi1=0;
var vi2=0;
function rotatevid() {
document.getElementById("myvideo").addEventListener("ended",switchvideo,false);
function switchvideo(e) {
  vi1++;
  vi2++;
  if (vi1==myvideo1.length) {
    vi1=0;
  }
  if (vi2==myvideo2.length) {
    =0;
  }
  document.getElementById("vmp4").src=myvideo1[vi1];
  document.getElementById("vogg").src=myvideo2[vi2];
}
setTimeout(rotatevid(), 5000);
}
```

Comment: You can check for the video ended event and than use setTimeOut and paly the next one

Comment: For reference https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_ended.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved, updating the answer**

```
<video id="myvideo" controls autoplay>
  <source id="vmp4" src="v1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source id="vogg" src="v1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <p>Your browser does not support this video format.</p>
</video>

<script>
  var count = 1;
  var vid = document.getElementById("myvideo");
  vid.addEventListener("ended", switchvideo, false);
  function switchvideo(e) {

    if (count % 2 === 0) {
      vid.setAttribute('src', 'v1.mp4');
    } else {
      vid.setAttribute('src', 'v2.mp4');
    }
    count++;
    vid.load();
    try {
      setTimeout(()=>vid.play(), 2000);
    } catch (err){
       console.log(err)
    }
  }
</script>
```

This is a working code. Just make sure you have v1.mp4 and v2.mp4 present in the same folder you are keeping this HTML File.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) framework for this.
in particular, you can use the [carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) component.